# Unable to load site with Delphi TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am trying  to load a site into delphi TwebBrowser.

I am using 10.3 Rio.

When I use:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var sURL:string;
begin
  sURL:='https://web.whatsapp.com/';
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(sURL);
end;
```

I am unable to load the site and I get the next message on browser:
"incompatible browser message" and says to use Chrome,FireFox or Opera.

Is there some workaround to solve it?

```
TMyWebBrowser = class (SHDocVw.TWebbrowser, IDispatch)
  private
    FUserAgent: string;
    procedure SetUserAgent (const Value: string);
    function Invoke(DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer; Flags: Word; var Params; VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer): HRESULT; stdcall;
  public
    property UserAgent: string read FUserAgent write SetUserAgent;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
      const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

    private
     WebBrowser1:TMyWebBrowser
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1:=TMyWebBrowser.Create(self);
  with WebBrowser1 do begin
    Align := alClient;
    TabOrder := 0;
    OnDocumentComplete := WebBrowser1DocumentComplete;
    TWinControl(WebBrowser1).Parent := Self;
  end;
  WebBrowser1.HandleNeeded;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var ua,sUrl:string;
begin
    ua:='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36';
    WebBrowser1.UserAgent:=ua;
    sUrl := 'https://web.whatsapp.com/';
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(sUrl);
end;

constructor TMyWebBrowser.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Silent := true;  //don't show JS errors
  FUserAgent:='';
end;

function TMyWebBrowser.Invoke(DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer; Flags: Word; var Params; VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer): HRESULT;
begin
  if (FUserAgent <> '') and (Flags and DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET <> 0) and Assigned(VarResult) and (DispId=DISPID_AMBIENT_USERAGENT) then
  begin
    POleVariant(VarResult)^:= FUserAgent+#13#10;
    Result := S_OK;
  end
  else
  Result := inherited Invoke(DispID, IID, LocaleID, Flags, Params, VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr);
end;

procedure TMyWebBrowser.SetUserAgent(const Value: string);
var
  Control: IOleControl;
begin
  FUserAgent := Value;
  if DefaultInterface.QueryInterface(IOleControl, Control) = 0 then
    Control.OnAmbientPropertyChange(DISPID_AMBIENT_USERAGENT);
end;
```

Comment: Set the browser agent string

Comment: Use embedded Chromium ([CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi)). TWebBrowser is IE based and it is outdated.

Comment: @David Hefferman   I did and I have the same problem. I updated the post.

Comment: You probably also need to make it use the latest version of the browser control, and not default to some IE6 compat mode. There are lots of posts on here about how to do that.

Comment: I did. I changed the windows registry to use IE11 with my test app. No look.

Comment: You should forget about TWebBrowser and IE at all and accept that some sites no longer work in outdated browsers. This site won't work in IE11 even with fake user-agent: http://prntscr.com/qkfv46

Comment: @zed It works fine in Edge, don't see any reason for it not to work in the standard browser control

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Edge is supported officially: http://prntscr.com/qkg7ei IE is not.

Comment: @zed It is possible to get past the UA detection using TWebBrowser, but I suspect that there is more to do, because I just get a spinning circle wait. I would not be surprised if it was just as tricky with CEF4Delphi.

Comment: @ David Heffernan  yes, this is the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan CEF4Delphi (demos\Delphi_VCL\SimpleBrowser) works fine: http://prntscr.com/qkoj05

Comment: See the latter part of the help on this page: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser

Comment: @Dave Nottage  I did and I continue with a spinning circle waiting.